# Cannot get values where column is null - angular

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

**Brief explanation**: I fetch count where Column `TASKID is null`.

**Result** -- The Result of cnt on console is **0**. But cnt should be **4**.

**Data** --

```
{SNO: 39157, TASKID: null},

{SNO: 39158, TASKID: 1},

{SNO: 39159, TASKID: null},

{SNO: 39160, TASKID: null},

{SNO: 39162, TASKID: null}
```

> **Requirement**: I want to fetch count of columns where column `TASKID is NULL`.

```
export class HomePage {  

constructor(){
    var dbName ='Demo';
    var tblnm = 'Test';
    var connection = new JsStore.Instance();
    connection.openDb(dbName);
    connection.count({
          from: tblnm,
          where :{
             TASKID : null
          }
    }).then(cnt =>{
          console.log(cnt); 
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: you want to get the sum of it? 
Basiclly you can use SUM(*) on SQL,
now if you want to do it on JS you can run over the result and check if result is NULL and counter++

Comment: I want to set condition in 'where'  TASKID is null.

Comment: I dont really know in which framework your using to fetch data, in SQL you can do "WHERE TASKID is NULL".